# Cross domain page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to refresh parent window from child window. Using following code in Child window this code reside in HTML widget.

```
parent.parent.window.opener.location.reload()
```

I am not adding any code in parent page since it is a moodle PHP page.
This code is working fine if both window reside in same origin.
I don't want to go with `post-message()`. because I dont want to touch parent window code. 
Can you help me with that? Just to refresh the page!!

Comment: I think you cannot manipulate a page from a different origin. ALso this is not a valid reason "since it is a moodle PHP page"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to make this work.

1) You need to place on HTML file with below code on the domain where parent page resides.
`pageReload.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function reload() {
     parent.parent.window.opener.location.reload();
};
</script>
</head>
<body onload="reload()">
</body>
</html>
```

2) Load this HTML page in Child window of HTML Widget code. Add below line of code to load the above page.

```
window.location = "http://www.yourparentdomain.com/pageReload.html";
```

After this cross-domain page refresh will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with a page from a different domain. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting